# Logout wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

When the user logs out they are seeing the following message:

> "You are attempting to log out of Website
>   Do you really want to log out?"

Is there anyway we can edit this text, or even better, bypass this? I tried using a shortcode, however the text on the page is being pulled by jQuery which is making this more complicated.

This is the link the user follows:

```
<li class="tml-user-link-logout">
  <a href="https://www.website.com/wp-login.php?action=logout">Log Out</a>
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: there's no php/jquery here.

Comment: JQuery and php tags removed.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked and solved here: [How to log out from WordPress without confirmation message?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out/), hopefully it will help you.